# SQL LEFT JOIN for joining three tables but one with to exclude content

Tags: sql, join, left-join, inner-join, outer-join

I have 3 tables

- STUDENTS
- FEES_PAID
- SUSPENDED

I want to get the details of the students who have paid the fees but not from `SUSPENDED`.

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM
    STUDENTS s
LEFT JOIN
    SUSPENDED p ON s.ID = p.ID
INNER JOIN 
    FEES_PAID f ON f.ID = s.ID
WHERE
    s.ID IS NULL
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Can any one suggest an efficient query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `WHERE p.ID IS NULL`?  *(This is an example of why aliases should have names that **mean** something, to make it clearer and easier to sanity check and maintain.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT
    s.ID
FROM
    STUDENTS s
LEFT JOIN
    SUSPENDED p
        ON s.ID=p.ID
INNER JOIN
    FEES_PAID f
        ON f.ID= s.ID
WHERE
    p.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the *second* table is missing from the `LEFT JOIN`.  So, you need to look at a column in that table.  Change the `WHERE` to:

```
WHERE p.ID IS NULL
```

Alternatively, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT s.ID
FROM STUDENTS s INNER JOIN
     FEES_PAID f
     ON f.ID = s.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SUSPENDED p WHERE s.ID = p.ID);
```

Note that for both these queries, you will need to qualify the `ID` in the `SELECT` to specify the table where it comes from.

Comment: Depending on the dialect, `NOT EXISTS` can be marginally quicker or significantly slower.  `LEFT JOIN` `NOT NULL` seems to be more generically applicable in my experience.

Comment: @MatBailie . . . I actually suggested it for clarity.  The OP seems a little confused on the joins, so I figured moving this logic to the `WHERE` clause would help him focus on the joins.